# Celery + rabbitmq in result backend

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

**tasks.py:**

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

**call.py:**

```
from tasks import add

result = add.delay(1, 4)

result.ready()
```

**celeryconfig.py:** (in the same directory)

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest@localhost//'

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://guest@localhost//'

CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'

CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json']

CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Oslo'

CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
```

In **call.py** I have en error:

> AttributeError: 'DisabledBackend' object has no attribute
>   '_get_task_meta_for'

I read the docs, I have result backend, why it does not work? How to fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You should not use `Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')` along with your celeryconfig.py file.

The way you should go (and the way of the documentation) is:

Create a package called **mypackage** (it is assumed that mypackage is not a sub package) with two files:

**celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from celery import Celery

app = Celery('mypackage',
             broker='amqp://guest@localhost//',
             backend='amqp://guest@localhost//',
             include=['mypackage.tasks'] #References your tasks. Donc forget to put the whole absolute path.
             )

app.conf.update(
        CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json',
        CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json',
        CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json'],
        CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Oslo',
        CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
                )
```

**tasks.py**

```
from mypackage.celery import app
@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Your call.py file is fine.

Start the Celery worker by using `celery -A mypackage worker` in command line, in the parent directory of **mypackage**.

Then you can start another Python interpreter, use call.py and voila!

Comment: I'm looking for how to use Rabbit as both broker and backend but I found in the docs that it shouldn't use amqp. [docs](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#std:setting-CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND)

Comment: @chachan that link is broken - can you elaborate?

Comment: @AmichaiSchreiber you're right. I don't see it anymore. Sorry

Answer (score -5):

I find a bug in my code. 
In **tasks.py**:

```
app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//', backend='amqp')
```

Needs backend parameter.

Comment: If you do that you will have issues with your configuration file, as you have a backend and a broker set twice. Assume you want to use a remote RabbitMQ broker, then which one do you change?